# Why do some array parameters have a comma after opening parentheses?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

What is this syntax I've seen some documentations applying, for example:

**[Jquery Sizzle](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki)**

`Sizzle( String selector[, DOMNode context[, Array results]] )`

**[Codeiginiter 3](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html)**

`set_userdata($data[, $value = NULL])`

Comment: I'm wondering too - saw the example syntax like this quite many times...

Comment: Because they might not want to start from `0`, and start from `1` index

Comment: @Tushar That's an interesting thought, actually.

Comment: @Tushar What do you mean?  Anyway, I believe it's a convention for optional parameters. Usually you would use a parenthesis in written text for something "optional" (like this comment), but since paranthesis are already used for regular parameters, you use square brackets to denote optional arguments. Like in maths, you first use regular parenthesis, then square, then curly for nested parenthesis

Comment: `for(var i = 1; i <= arr.len;` might sound good to some developers

Comment: @Tushar I still don't see how that relates to the current question...OP's talking about documentation, not actual code snippets

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, what this means, is that all parameters inside the `[]` are optional. You dont need to pass anything in order to make the function call work:

```
foo($param [, $param2 = NULL, $param3 = 1])
```

`$param1` and `$param2` are optional, $param is mandatory.

Comment: In what language they don't have to follow the order?

Comment: Javascript for example.

Comment: So, in JS I can use `prompt("Name:", "Your name");` as well as `prompt("Your name", "Name");` and the browser know what i expect from that prompt?

Comment: That is not correct. It depends on how the function is defined and how it works internally. Jquery for instance 'on' method, if you pass 2 parameters, the first is the selector and the second the function, if you pass 3, the first is the delegator, the second the selector and the third the function. I did not state that everything in javascript works this way.

Comment: "and can be in any order"  This is not true.  **Some** jQuery functions let you *skip* parameters.  In that case, you would see ***multiple*** definitions in the doc to explain this.

Comment: No, but you've said that in `foo($param [, $param2 = NULL, $param3 = 1])` `$param1` and `$param2` don't have to follow the order. They must do it. If it is PHP, order is very important.

Comment: True, I stand corrected. Not every language works the same way.

Comment: This is pretty standard notation. PHP uses it, you can also see as an example of nested optional parameters on the [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function where some optional parameters then also have their own set of optional parameters.

Comment: Nice, had seen this for a while, looked weird at first. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Those parentheses show that those parameters are optional in syntax.
This examples aren't code lines, but syntax.

Valid code lines:

```
Sizzle(selector, context, results);
Sizzle(selector, context);
Sizzle(selector);
set_userdata($data, $value);
set_userdata($data);
```

But, if we take a look at @taxicala answer we have another situation

```
foo($param [, $param2 = NULL, $param3 = 1])
```

Valid code lines are

```
foo($param, $param2, $param3)
foo($param)
```

but not

```
foo($param, $param2)
```